# Run OLS with multicollinearity

Tags: regression, least-squares, stata, multicollinearity, treatment-effect

I apologize for my naive question.

In [this famous experiment](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.0956-7976.2004.00757.x?casa_token=2ALMQBE39gkAAAAA:tO5ixH-xCdQ47SphNnrmg7iWa4JjOEPUtsd8DpkM4RZqAnSrDUOcOcOVYoLXCWfH3dk1Ewayg313) they collected responses in 4 different groups:

- Control (no rewards provided)
- Gift reward (10 pieces of candy or 50 pieces of candy)
- Monetized gift reward (10 pieces of candy worth 10 USD or 50 pieces of candy worth 50 USD)
- Cash reward (10 USD or 50 USD)

The results showed that gift rewards without monetary value put people in a social frame and don't act according to the reward. On the other hand, putting a $ worth to a gift makes people react as if it's cash (price-sensitive).

I'm running a very similar experiment, but I wonder how I can run OLS properly without collinearity issues. The problem is that the "no" level of payment is exactly the same as the control group. Could you lead me to how to specify the exogenous variables correctly? For now I can think of the following 4:

- Reward (0 for controls, 1 for treatments)
- Gift (0 for controls and cash, 1 for the 2 candy treatments)
- Monetary (0 for controls, candy, 1 for $candy, cash)
- Level (0 for controls, 1 for low, 2 for high)

Thank you very much

[image: expected willingness to help by payment level and form]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it seems like there is a full factorial design embedded in here, you actually just have seven distinct experimental conditions. Instead of trying to parameterize this with several variables, just use one variable representing experimental condition. Then test your hypotheses using contrasts. For example, if you want to compare low groups to medium conditions, you can compare the average of the low groups to the average of the medium groups (i.e., by taking the average of the corresponding regression coefficients and testing whether the difference of the average differs from zero). You can also specify certain interaction tests using this method. Depending on the software you use, it may be easier to specify this as a oneway ANOVA than as a regression.

Comment: Thank you very much!!